# How to combine rows in excel? (Large dataset)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, merge, sum, consolidation

I have a large dataset (>79000 rows). My dataset looks like this:

| Col1 | Sampl1 | Sampl2 | Sampl3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sp1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 1.2 |
| sp2 | 1 | 2.1 | 4 |
| sp3 | 2 | 3 | 0.75 |
| sp1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

I want to combine the duplicate columns in the species column while also summing the values in the samples' columns so my dataset will look like this:

| Col1 | Sampl1 | Sampl2 | Sampl3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sp1 | 1.1 | 4.5 | 2.2 |
| sp2 | 1 | 2.1 | 4 |
| sp3 | 2 | 3 | 0.75 |

I have tried using the consolidate function in excel but it did not produce anything after loading (I would select my references and the "sum" function, I waited, and after it loaded nothing appeared in the new sheet).

Comment: I would use Power Query for this when working with larger datasets.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, this can be **performed** more **elegantly** using `Power Query` without any issue. May be there can be more **eloquent solutions** to this, but i will personally use **Power Query** here when dealing with **larger datasets** where i need to **Group** by **duplicates** and **sum** the **respective values**. **Note** that this is a one time approach, next time when you add **new data** to your **source data**, you just need to **refresh** the table **imported** using **Power Query**.

---

So that said, you can follow the steps to perform the task using **Power Query**

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data** Tab => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the **Tables Names**,

• Paste the **M Code** below in place of what you see.

---

**Approach One:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Col1"}, {{"Sample1", each List.Sum([Sampl1]), type number}, {"Sample2", each List.Sum([Sampl2]), type number}, {"Sample3", each List.Sum([Sampl3]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

**Or Approach Two:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Col1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

You can use either of the one, but using the **Second One** will be more succinct.

• Change the Table name if required before importing it back into Excel.

• From **Home** Tab => **Close & Load** => **Close & Load To**

• When **importing**, you can either select **Existing Sheet** with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on **NewSheet**

---

[image]

---

**Approach One --> Screenshots**

[image]

---

**Approach Two --> Screenshots**

[image]

---

An **Excel Formula** alternative approach using **New MS365 functions**. -->

<kbd>REDUCE</kbd>
<kbd>UNIQUE</kbd>
<kbd>BYCOL</kbd>
<kbd>LAMBDA</kbd>
<kbd>VSTACK</kbd>
<kbd>HSTACK</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=REDUCE(A1:D1,UNIQUE(A2:A5),
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,
BYCOL(B2:D5,LAMBDA(m,SUM((A2:A5=y)*m)))))))
```

---

The formula approach also works fine for me, <kbd>Tested</kbd> with <kbd>86017</kbd> rows of data and here is a **[sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cizwwreIHXw1BnBvo?e=teBpjZ)**.

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Simpler formulas are UNIQUE and SUMIFS:

F5 `=UNIQUE(A5:A8)`

G5 `=SUMIF($A$5:$A$8,$F5,B$5:B$8)` - drag or copy this as far as you need.

Or create a pivot table with Col1 in the Rows section, and Sampl1, Sampl2, etc. in the Values section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Unique Data

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:D7,
    du,INDEX(data,,1),u,UNIQUE(du),dv,DROP(data,,1),
    dr,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(u)),LAMBDA(rr,r,
        LET(f,FILTER(dv,du=INDEX(u,r)),
            VSTACK(rr,BYCOL(f,LAMBDA(c,SUM(c))))))),1),
HSTACK(u,dr))
```